# Fallo Mysql workbench error 1215

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo que hacer una base de datos de un hospital, soy nueva en mysql y en este foro. Me sale el error al crear la foreing key.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `hospital2`;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `hospital2` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci */;
USE `hospital2`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `admin`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
    `usuario` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
    `apellidos` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `passw` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
    `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `foto` longblob
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `area`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `area` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `tipo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `color` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `orientacion` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `asignado`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `asignado` (
    `idTrabajador` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `idTurno` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`idTrabajador`,`idTurno`),
    KEY `idTurno` (`idTurno`),
    CONSTRAINT `asignado_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idTrabajador`)    REFERENCES `trabajador` (`colegiado`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `asignado_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idTurno`) REFERENCES     `turno` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- Volcando estructura para tabla hospital.tipoturno
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tipoturno`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tipoturno` (
`tipo` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`horaentrada` time DEFAULT NULL,
`horasalida` time DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`tipo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `trabajador`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trabajador` (
`colegiado` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`nif` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
`nombre` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
`apellidos` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
`telefono` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`direccion` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`nacionalidad` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`provincia` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`ciudad` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`fecha_nacimiento` date DEFAULT NULL,
`sexo` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`activo` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`foto` longblob,
`idArea` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`passw` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`colegiado`),
KEY `idArea` (`idArea`),
KEY `colegiado` (`colegiado`),
CONSTRAINT `trabajador_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idArea`) REFERENCES `area`       (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;
```

Comment: La verdad tengo rato sin crear bases de datos de esa manera.  No te hace falta que exista la tabla trabajador y turno? para poder usar References.

Comment: ¿Puede indicar la estructura de las tablas `trabajador` y `turno`?.

Comment: Si perdona es que es bastante largo y no quería pegarlo todo, he intentado cambiarlo y que las keys sean todas del mismo tipo (varchar(9)) y nada. Gracias

Comment: Agregó la tabla `trabajador` pero no la tabla `turno`. En el siguiente ejemplo: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/adYcJYLEv9d48Kq7QYbCqc/0), puede ver la creación de las tablas (excluyendo `turno`).

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes relaciones asegurate que tengas creados los `index` por ahi debe de venir el problema, es decir (ejemplo):
Tu tabla `usuarios` con `id` como llave primaria. y tu tabla `ventas` con una columna `id_usuario` aqui el `id_usuario` debe llevar `index` asegurate que tus relaciones sean así, para que no te marque error. Saludos!

Comment: la llave foránea para funcionar no necesita ser index, de hecho index es con otro fin de optimización de búsquedas mas no de lo que mencionas